# Adobe Premiere preview video lagging

Tags: video, video-editor, premiere, preview

I am attempting to edit video in Adobe Premiere CS6. When I create a sequence and try to play it back in the preview screen, the video is extremely choppy, which makes editing very difficult (dance videos, i.e. trying to sync with music properly).

After some searching, two things seem to work for others - either changing playback quality to 1/4 or 1/2, or rendering the work area before playback. The former seems to have no effect, although the latter (rendering) does create smooth video.

Unfortunately, when the render finishes, the video is now playing in super slow motion, and is therefore completely out of sync with the music. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does the audio play back smoothly before you render?  If the source video is being interpolated incorrectly (say 2.4 FPS instead of 24 or something similar) then it would preview as very "jumpy" since it was only changing frames every 10 frames, but the audio could still play back correctly in certain formats.  The rendering could interpolate the intermediate frames and make things appear more smoothly, but would appear very slow.  Even if this isn't the case, something very odd is clearly going on with your project which may make it hard to diagnose remotely (but I can give it a try.)

Comment: I tested it on another computer (powerful desktop, as opposed to my laptop) today, and confirmed. audio and video are fine beforehand - slow and choppy on my computer, but good enough on the desktop to edit the video.

when I select a work area and try to render it, audio remains fine, and video slows down. i.e. if I select 30 seconds of video to render, the result is 30 secs of audio and about 20 secs of video stretched to fill 30 sec in slomo.

if its pertinent, my raw files are 1440x1080, 59.96 fps. I've never worked with anything past basics before, so I may have made beginner's mistakes.

Comment: ok, well that's a very weird resolution and very high frame rate.  It isn't all that surprising that it is causing problems with playback on a lower end system since the data rate is probably far too high for the hard disks to keep up with and may well be too much for the CPU to keep up with as well.  As for the slow down, it may be a problem with how the footage is being interpreted.  Have you tried rendering the project on your desktop to see if you have the same slowdown problem?

Comment: yeah, its very high (wish i could've chosen the camera!). it is too taxing for my laptop, which is why i tried a desktop today - the same problem is there. i may be importing (and subsequently exporting) the videos with bad settings, i think. as a side note, the video preview without rendering is smooth enough on the desktop for me to edit, but i can't seem to find the right export settings (smooth, but artifacts in the video) - im searching for common solutions to that, but it may be related.

Comment: You may have accidentally unlinked your video from your audio and stretched the footage. If you rendered it for a preview and it plays choppy then that is your computer unable to keep up. If you rendered it as a preview and it plays in slow motion and is actually stretched out longer than it actually is then you probably accidentally stretched it somehow. It's easy enough to do with the Rate Stretch Tool (R).

Comment: I just made the original video file an .mp4 instead of .mov
problem solved for me

Comment: 1440×1080 is the resolution for HDV (non-square pixels). 59.96 fps might mean that it's interlaced. Check your interpretation settings for the file.

Comment: How much ram do you have on your computer? It could just be a simple hardware issue. Premiere Pro suggests at least 8gb

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a combination of two things from the comments discussion.  First, with the very high frame rate, your laptop simply can not handle the high data rate.  If you need to edit on the laptop, I would suggest re-compressing the video down to a smaller size and then when you are done, you can replace the low quality footage with the original for the final output.

The second problem is that it appears Premiere is interpreting the footage wrong.  There is an  Interpret Footage option if you right click on the clip and go to Modify, Interpret Footage.  You can confirm the frame rate is correct on the source.  If it is, then you also want to check the framerate on the sequence itself.  Right click on the sequence, choose Sequence Settings and verify that the frame rate is correct there as well.  If both of those are correct and you are still getting the issues, then I am unsure what could be happening.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92264/discussion-on-answer-by-aj-henderson-adobe-premiere-preview-video-lagging).

Answer (score 1):

I used to get stuck with this problem. I finally solved it by changing the "video playback settings" from "the sequence settings" in the "sequence" menu. The default resolution is 1920 x 1080. I changed it to 640 x 360, and after that playback was always 100% smooth, even while using a mixture of .mts and .mvi full HD files, with contrast and brightness effects on them, without even having to render at all, even while the bar is red.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem, after rendering video, it would slow down to half speed. Not sure why, but the only way to get back to the whole clip was to click "Sequence" "delete render files"

Doesn't solve the problem of rendering, but it gets back to the original full speed clip.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are overthinking it. Simple solution

-Right click on your sequence
-Select Sequence Settings
-Under Preview File Format select "P2 1080i"

basically anything but the default "I-frame"

Answer (score 0):

If video is choppy and laggy, like some of my gaming videos that are at least an hour long....

They are lagging when I'm mining in Minecraft. It may be how much video you are putting in there all in one clip. For example, when I put in my one hour gameplay, when I first start to mine, it is laggy.

To all of the new comers, use Adobe Media Encoder. Use the settings that you want, and it will encode the video and make it less choppy. When I did this, it made my videos less choppy. Although it takes a couple of hours for a long video, it is well organized when it is finished.

I know I sound like I'm not explaining, this app from Adobe is really helpful, but it can get annoying at some times. So, I might find a new way soon. But, this is my suggestion to everyone who is new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to sequence menu - sequence settings - check if timebase is correct with video metadata - display format (under video) - choose frames/nondropframe timecode.

BROUGHT MI FRAMES BACK!!!